# Banach Steinhaus Theorem

Tags: calculus, general-topology, linear-transformations

Let $ U,W $ be nomred vector space over $ \mathbb{C}$, and let $V $ be a Banach vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $ F:U\times V\to W $ be such function, that for any $ u \in U $, the function $ F\left(u,\cdot\right):V\to W $ is a continuous linear transformation, and for any $ v\in V $ the function $ F\left(.,v\right):U\to W $ is a continuous function (not necessarily a linear function).

Now let $ \left\{ u_{n}\right\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq U,\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\left\{ v_{n}\right\} _{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq V $ be sequences that converges to the $ 0 $ vector (each in the correspondent space).

Prove that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}F\left(u_{n},v_{n}\right)=0 $.

Im new to this subject so Im not sure how to approach, but here's what I've tried.

Define for any $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ the linear transformation $ T_{n}\left(v\right)=F\left(u_{n},v\right) $, and notice that for any $ v\in V $ we have by continuity of $ F(.,v) $ :

$ T_{n}\left(v\right)=F\left(u_{n},v\right)\to F\left(0,v\right) $

And thus, as a convergent sequence, we have for any $ v\in V $ :

$ \sup_{n}||T_{n}\left(v\right)||=\sup_{n}||F\left(u_{n},v\right)||<\infty $

Since $ V $ is a Banach space, we can use Banach Steinhaus Theorem to conclude that

$ \sup_{n}||T_{n}||\leq C $

for some constant $ C $. That is:

$ \sup_{n}\left(\sup_{||v||\leq1}||T_{n}\left(v\right)||\right)=\sup_{n}\left(\sup_{||v||\leq1}||F\left(u_{n},v\right)||\right)\leq C $.

Now fix $ \varepsilon >0 $. Since $ ||v_{n}||\to0 $ also $ \sqrt{||v_{n}||}\to0 $ and $ \frac{v_{n}}{\sqrt{||v_{n}||}}\to0 $.

So there exists $ N $ such that for any $ n\geq N $ we have

$ ||\frac{v_{n}}{\sqrt{||v_{n}||}}||<1 $

And also $ \sqrt{||v_{n}||}<\frac{\varepsilon}{C+1} $.

Thus for any $ n \geq N $ we have

$ ||F\left(u_{n},v_{n}\right)||=||T_{n}\left(v_{n}\right)||=\sqrt{||v_{n}||}||T_{n}\left(\frac{v_{n}}{\sqrt{||v_{n}||}}\right)||\leq\sqrt{||v_{n}||}C<\varepsilon $

I'd like to hear if this proof holds, and also I would be happy to see a better proof if anyone can suggest such proof.

Thanks in advance.